# Suddenly keyboard crashes while using it

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, vmware

I use VMware and have Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

While running Ubuntu, my keyboard works well at first but suddenly the keys start not working well: e.g. when I press <kbd>s</kbd> in Libre Office Writer it tries to save and I'm not able to write anything and my keyboard becomes like when you have pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

Any help on how to solve this?

Comment: It sounds like a broken Ctrl key... so does 'Alt'+'t' open terminal, 'w' close tabs etc?

Comment: pressing 's' becomes like pressing 'ctrl'+'s', 'q' like 'ctrl' + 'q',pressing 't' becomes like pressing 'ctrl' + 't', ...

Comment: Have you tried hitting both [Ctrl] keys forcibly a few times?  Do they "unstick" then??? (*really* looks like a broken keyboard)

Comment: I don't have this problem on my windows
It just happens when I use Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware